# Proprietary Drivers Required for my Lenovo Edge 320

Tags: wireless, drivers, lenovo, proprietary

Sooo...I have ordered myself a Lenovo Thinkpad Edge 320. I'm realy excited about the Laptop and about trying Ubuntu. I'm completly new to linux. So i did find out that the laptop is certified for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-Bit, but it says that Proprietary Drivers for WiFi functionality is required. Basically i have absolutly no idea what that means, or what i have to do, to make WiFi work.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the hardware for your Wifi card requires drivers that are not open-source and are not supplied by the open-source community.

To install those drivers you need and internet connection (use your LAN cable to connect to your router), and on the Unity dash look for an application called `Additional Drivers` and run it. You can then select what hardware requires extra proprietary drivers and activate those drivers.

Ubuntu will then download and install any extra required drivers to make your hardware work and after that is done you can enjoy connecting wireless to a network again.

Answer (score 0):

Your laptop needs proprietary drivers for wireless to function (in contrast to open-source).
People have encountered problems with the drivers, though it has lessened with the newer versions of Ubuntu.
There is nothing to do;Ubuntu comes prepackaged with the proprietary drivers (at least for my model).

Comment: You need to specify for the OP's model, not for your model.